# Understanding this example of projective geometry in Algebraic matroids

Tags: algebraic-geometry, matroids

In this paper by Evans and Hrushovski: https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s3-62.1.1
 they characterize projective planes in algebraically closed fields. These are coordinated by the skew-fields of quotients of the endomorphism rings of connected one-dimensional algebraic groups.

I'm trying to understand their "Example 2" (which is actually the general construction according to Theorem 3.3.1), in which (the representation of) all the ground set elements are of the form $\alpha_1x_1*\alpha_2x_2*\alpha_3x_3$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are independent generic elements of a connected one-dimensional algebraic group $(G, *)$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in {\rm End}(G)$ not all $0$.

I tried understanding it by looking at examples that I know, but I haven't managed. For example (this is their Example 1), if $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are algebraically independent over the algebraically closed field $\mathbb{K}$, we can look at all the elements $x_1^{m_1}\cdot x_2^{m_2}\cdot x_3^{m_3}$ with $m_1,m_2,m_3\in \mathbb{Z}$ not all $0$. This example (extended to general rank) shows that matroids linear over $\mathbb{Q}$ are algebraic in all characteristics (?).

Second example, we look at all the elements $\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2 x_2+\alpha_3 x_3$ with $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\in \mathbb{K}$ not all $0$. This example (extended to general rank) is usually used to show that every linear matroid is algebraic over the same field.

If I understand correctly, then in the first case $G=\mathbb{G}_m(\overline{\mathbb{K}(x_1,x_2,x_3)})$ with ${\rm End}(G)=\{x\mapsto x^m\ |\ m\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, while in the second case $G=\mathbb{G}_a(\overline{\mathbb{K}(x_1,x_2,x_3)})$ and the endomorphisms in the example are $x\mapsto \alpha x$. If ${\rm char}(\mathbb{K})=0$ these are all (?), but otherwise in the second case there are more because $x\mapsto x^p$ is also an endomorphism (?).

I guess my first question is if I understood correctly so far.

My main question is regarding the general construction, because there is another case they describe in the paper (other than $G=\mathbb{G}_m$ and $G=\mathbb{G}_a$), where $G$ is an elliptic curve. I don't understand how the elements look in this case, i.e., how the multiplication and isogenies work here to generate a general element. I'm not even sure what a generic element of $G$ means here - is it a uniformizer for the curve?

I'd really appreciate it if someone could give me some concrete example with a concrete elliptic curve (preferably a simple non-trivial one).

Answer (score 1):

If a matroid is linear over the endomorphism ring of a connected one-dimensional algebraic group, then it is algebraic. This leaves the 3 options described in section 3.1 and mentioned by you. So I guess your question is how to go from a linear representation over the endomorphism ring to an algebraic representation in general. It is answered in the introduction of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.08692).

Sections 6.3 and 8.3 of [this PhD thesis](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/110949529/20181207_Bollen.pdf) might also interest you, and contain a few examples.

Comment: Thanks Guus, I will have a look at your paper and PhD. However, I was sort of hoping for an explicit example with elliptic curves, which (apparently since it is more complex) I could not find anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

An example of an algebraic representation over $\mathbb{F}_2$ of the matroid $M(K_4)$ is the following, where a triple is on a line if and only if it is algebraically dependent:

[image: Algebraic representation of M(K4)]

Here the group multiplication is defined by $$x * y = \frac{x+y}{1+xy}.$$
This group is neither $\mathbb{G}_a$ nor $\mathbb{G}_m$, so it is the group of an elliptic curve, although I am not sure which one.

Comment: But the order of every element in this group is $2$ ($x*x*x=x$), so why isn't the group isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_a(\mathbb{F})$?

Comment: The same can be said of any elliptic curve in characteristic 2: elliptic curves are additive groups, but not necessarily the additive group of $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant: this group is not only abelian, it is also isomorphic to an additive group of a field of characteristic $2$ (because it is an elementary abelian 2-group, i.e., the order of every element is $2$). I don't think there are (m)any  elliptic curves in which $x*x*x=x$ (i.e., $x*x=0$) for all $x\in G$ - geometrically this doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Actually, for _every_ elliptic curve $G$ defined over a field of characteristic 2, each $x \in G$ satisfies $x * x = 0$. Indeed, elliptic curves in characteristic 2 are a special breed.

Comment: Do you have a reference/proof for this statement? It seems to quite contradict what I've understood about elliptic curve groups.

Comment: For instance the section about characteristic 2 at http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/courses/m5410/ctcellip.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood what is written there - it is written that the form (2) doesn't work in characteristic $2$, as in this case indeed it would be that $2P=O$ for all the points. But, the form (2) ***is not*** the correct form for elliptic curves in characteristic $2$, because in characteristic $2$ it is singular.  Quoting from your reference: "... observe that the formula (2) does not work well in characteristic $2$ ...if $P$ has coordinates $(x,y)$, our **previous** computation would have $-P = (x,-y)$ ...  in characteristic $2$ we have $-P = (x,1+y)$".

Comment: You are right, I did misunderstand. Thank you. I will have to think about this/another example a bit more.

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, I think I already understand a bit better. But I'm now convinced that the group in this example is isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_a$ and not an elliptic curve group, so I still don't know how such a construction would look.

Comment: Would a similar algebraic representation with the group action $x*y = \frac{x+y+xy}{1+xy}$ be a better candidate? It is commutative, associative, and $x*x*x = x^4$.

Comment: You mean $x*x*x*x=x^4$. It might be correct - I tried to think about this example a bit, but I'm still confused. Maybe you could give some reasoning why it should be an elliptic curve group, and not isomorphic to $\mathbb{G}_m$? Could you also just define $x*y=x+y+xy$ or would this not work?